# Get value of dropdown selected option attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, select

I have added a drop down attribute with data in the product, now I need to get the selected value of option, not label, label i can get via getAttributeText('provider');?>, but i need get only selected value option

Comment: i think you have try with this code and get value proper                                                                                                        
 <?php $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>

Comment: it outputs non-value option, i need get only value option, not label

Comment: can you try this <?php    $attributeExist =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('packaging');

    if ($attributeExist->usesSource()) {
        echo $option_id = $attributeExist->getSource()->getOptionId($packaging); 
    }  ?>

Comment: just try `<?php $_product->getProvider();?>`

Comment: @Lerry you have got a solution?